# kafka topic partition rebalance notification

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using Kafka 0.8.1.1

Is there any API (callback etc.) using which the `lost partitions` or `newly added partitions` to a consumer could be found?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Kafka 0.9.1 API and there is an interface ConsumerRebalanceListener with two methods

public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection partitions)
where

**partitions** The list of partitions that were assigned to the consumer on the last rebalance

public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection partitions)

**partitions** The list of partitions that are now assigned to the consumer (may include partitions previously assigned to the consumer)